# Создать свой оператор C#

Tags: c#, типы-данных

Хочу переписать оператор деления на свой!!!
(оператор "/" Какой-то идиотизм с ним. Мелкософт почему-то думает, что деля целое на целое должно быть целое... float a=1/10 будет 0...)

У меня будет свой тип данных!!!
Хочу так:

```
    Новый тип данных My_data //строка-число 
    {
       длина-32 байта; состоит из базового типа char;
    Оператор div :
        a1,a2 new My_data;
        return Побитовое_деление(Переводим_строку_в_биты(а1),Переводим_строку_в_биты(а1));
    }
```

Функции Побитовое_деление и Переводим_строку_в_биты реализую сам. Интересует синтаксис объявления своего типа данных и ОПЕРАТОРА!!! Чтобы можно было просто:

```
My_data a1,a2,a3;
a3= a1 div a1;
```

Comment: `Мелкософт почему-то думает, что деля целое на целое должно быть целое...` ну вы же тоже хотите деля свой `My_data` на `My_data` получать `My_data`, а не, скажем, `double`. Почему?

Comment: `float a = 1.0f/10.0f;`

Comment: Так вы же сами пишите целые. Но раз на то пошло, то используйте перегрузку оперетора `float` и своей структуры в самой структуре и если делаете вдруг целые, то при помощи `float.Parse(число)` если ошибка парсинга то значит число не имеет дроби, значит добавляйте `.0` и не будет вам целого.

Comment: В C# это сделать невозможно. Точка. Если хотите создавать произвольные операторы, то возьмите другой язык программирования, который это позволяет. Например, Nemerle - этот язык довольно близок к C# и имеет мощную систему макросов. PS: долбите Microsoft требованиями добавить в C# метапрограммирование.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, невозможно что? Сделать перегрузку и условие на нецелые?

Comment: @And - невозможно создать свой оператор. Например, с именем `div`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, тут скорее это было как описание, а так нельзя да, а оно и не нужно в принципе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В документации есть [примеры перегрузки операторов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) и [список перегружаемых операторов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading#overloadable-operators).

Запрещено:

- Перегружать операторы, не входящие в список разрешенных для пергрузки, например, оператор присваивания.
- Создание новых пользовательских операторов (я имею ввиду определение дополнительных символов операторов и ключевых слов, которые компилятор сможет опознать как оператор). Это не поддерживается языком ни в каком виде.
- Переопределять операторы для типов, которые определены в чужих библиотеках, включая системные.

Пример перегрузки оператора деления (без логики, это уже пишите сами)

```
class MyData
{
    //прочие члены класса
    ...
    //определяем новый оператор
    public static MyData operator /(MyData a, MyData b)
    {
        MyData result;
        result = //логика вычисления результата
        return result;
    }
    ...
    //прочие члены класса
}
```

Как использовать:

```
MyData a, b;
MyData res = a / b;
```

Технически, вам ни кто не запрещает творить всякую дичь, вроде такого:

```
//определяем новый оператор
public static double operator /(MyData a, string b)
{
    return //что-то возвращаем
}
```

Но тут важно помнить, что один из параметров оператора **обязан** иметь тип класса, в котором он определен. Ну и надо не запутаться потом в этих дебрях с "дикими" операторами. Сделать код сложным для понимания вплоть до полного отсутствия понимая самим автором как и зачем оно работает гораздо проще, чем сделать его понятным, так что не увлекайтесь без реальной необходимости.

---

Любите документацию! Читайте документацию к инструментам, которые используете, и пишите ее к инструментам, которые создаете.

Comment: Но до кучи если будем хотеть `+,-,*,-=,+=,/=,*=` - это раскроется в тучу методов и костылей с перегрузками. Проще сделать через `implicit` в одной структуре, перегрузить `int, float, etc...`, они нативно будут работать и все эти плюсики с делениями и умножениями. вычитаниями, будут работать без их перегрузки и дополнительных каких-то расчетов.

Comment: @And не совсем так. всякие += и прочие сочетания с = будут работать при определении базового оператора, который они расширяют, если нет перегруженной версии расширенного оператора. Ну и не для всех данных применимо преобразование к базовым типам. Попробуйте привести к int матрицу например. В общем для математики достаточно переопределить базовые операторы `+ - * /` возможно еще `%`, остальное подхватится само.

Comment: А зачем матрицы? Тут дело про целые и плавающие числа, которые оперируют между собой. за место 4 перегрузок, юзать всего 1 через сам же оператор.

Comment: @And ну там нет указаний на длину обрабатываемых чисел, может банально не поместиться. В любом случае автора не устраивает поведение оператора деления для стандартных чисел. Возможно переход с паскаля или его производных сказывается, там два отдельных оператора для целочисленного и не целочисленного деления. Мне тоже не очень нравится это соглашение о выводе типа из типов операндов, но уже привык, оно раздражает куда меньше чем соглашение "x != 0 => true" в c/cpp

Comment: Но в спецификации говорится, что существует 3 оператора деления, целочисленный, плавающий и десятичный, просто нужно выбрать правильный подход. Я не знаю, что у автора в голове, но если правильно использовать, то все будет работать как нужно. И я думаю проблема с делением решиться если использовать литерал `xf` или же каст `(float)x/(float)y`. Просто деление целых чисел происходит быстрее и проще. А вот то, что плавающие могут нести не точный результат, это должно быть известно всем.

Comment: @And операторов разумеется три - в том смысле что три перегрузки на одном значке. Значок один. Т.е. визуально это один и тот же оператор.

Comment: Кто нибудь может коротенький код привести, с созданием собственного типа данных строка (для примера!). По идее с ключевым словом Struct

Comment: @СаакШахламджян а для чего вам собственная строка? Чем не устраивает базовый `string`? Если нужны дополнительные методы для существующего типа - на то есть методы-расширения. Свой тип имеет смысл создавать тогда, когда не существует подходящего среди готовых.

Comment: @СаакШахламджян если я вас неправильно понял "коротенький код привести, с созданием собственного типа данных строка", разверните мысль несколько шире, там посмотрим.